# cref change "range phrase"

Tags: cleveref

I use  `\crefname{equation}{}{}` to get rid of the "eqs." thingie.
When I use something like

```
\cref{eq:1,eq:2,eq:3}
```

I get

(1) to (3)

but I'd rather get
(1)-(3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding

```
\crefrangeformat{equation}{(#3#1#4)-(#5#2#6)}
```

in the preamble.

(Or see p. 16 of the `cleveref` documentation.)

Answer (score 4):

Alternative solution, add the following to the pre-amble.

```
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}
```

This solution has less configurability than the one posted by Thomas.

Styling note: the en dash (`--`) can be replaced by an ordinary hyphen (`-`), but most styles would prefer the en dash.