# Autoref range of sections etc

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing

Is it possible to use `\autoref` to reference a range of sections? I would like to replace

```
In Sections \ref{section1} -- \ref{section3} ...
```

with something like

```
In \autoref{section1, section2, section3} ...
```

As far as I know this is possible for citations, but does any package also offer this feature for references?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about `autoref`, but you did ask for package alternatives. The package [cleveref](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) provides this. With `cleveref` you would need to encode your section lables with the preceeding `sec:`. Writing the appended code produces

> ... sections 1 to 3.

We didn't even need to provide the sections in order! If you want

> ... sections 1 - 3

then use the simple answer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306863/cref-change-range-phrase) post.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    
\section{Name A}
\label{sec:a}
Blah Blah Blah.

\section{Name B}
\label{sec:b}
Blah Blah Blah.

\section{Name C}
\label{sec:c}
Blah Blah Blah.

\section{Conclusion}
\label{sec:conclusion}

We draw this conclusion from the discussion in \cref{sec:a,sec:c,sec:b}.
Alternatively, may write \crefrange{sec:a}{sec:c}.

\end{document}
```

[image: Output generated by the above code.]

Comment: Also, I'm sorry that I don't know how to add pdf output to my answer.

Comment: Simply make a screenshot and add the output as a picture`:-)`